# I cannot login to my magento 2.0 admin panel

Tags: magento2, login, magento-2.0

I have successfully installed magento 2.0 However I cannot see any default theme appled on the front end and also I am not able to login to my admin panel

Comment: please remove var/cache folder and and try

Comment: @KeyulShah It isn't working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please enable the rewrite_module from apache module and clear the cache. Hope it will solve your problem

[image]